# How can I do partial substitution in R?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, substitution

A quick example:

```
expr <- quote(x^t)
t <- 2
```

What I want to get is the expression `x^2`.

```
library(pryr)
subs(expr) # x^t
subs(expr, list(t=2)) # expr
```

Comment: The line `expr <- x^t` should be throwing an error (unless you've previously defined both `x` and `t` in that case it's not returning an expression, but a numeric value). Are you doing `expr <- quote(x^t)` or something?

Comment: Apologies - yes. It  should be `quote(x^t)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using base R, you could so something like

```
expr <- quote(x^t)
do.call("substitute", list(expr, list(t=2)))
# x^2
```

Comment: Whereas just calling substitute would not evaluate its argument, right?

Comment: It would not. If you called `substitute(expr)`, it would treat `expr` as an expression and not resolve it to `x^t`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively (and paralleling the example of how to do this given in the [R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Substitutions)), you can use `substitute()` twice.

```
expr <- quote(x^t)
eval(substitute(substitute(e, list(t=2)), list(e=expr)))
# x^2
```

Comment: can you explain what is going on here?  For example, why the  double substitute?  I have seen this idiom before, but am a little confused by it.

Comment: @ChristopherBrown -- The best way to see what it's doing is to look at the result of running `substitute(substitute(e, list(t=2)), list(e=expr))`, and to figure out why it is what it is. The key bit to understand is that in that  statement, the whole expression `substitute(e,list(t=2))` is being treated as the `expr` argument of the outer `substitute()` call. (I think that what makes this idiom initially hard to grock is that we're used to evaluating outwards from the innermost set of parentheses, but in this case that's not what happens...) HTH.